# What's causing list contents to clear?

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to store results from a BQL statement in a list by looping through and adding the objects to the list during a PXAction, so I can run some checks against the list later in a FieldUpdated event. However When I get to the FieldUpdated event, the contents of the list are back to zero.

```
 public class SOShipmentEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOShipmentEntry>
    {
public PXSelectJoin<INItemLotSerial, InnerJoin<SOShipLine, On<INItemLotSerial.inventoryID, Equal<Current<SOShipLine.inventoryID>>>>, Where<SOShipLine.shipmentNbr, Equal<Current<SOShipment.shipmentNbr>>>> AvailSerialList;
        List<INItemLotSerial> AvailToPick = new List<INItemLotSerial>();
```

Here's where I add results into the list (added a watch on debugger to make sure I have a count of the content added, and verify that the list has content)

```
  public PXAction<SOShipment> uploadlotserial;
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Upload LotSerial", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
        [PXButton]
        public virtual IEnumerable uploadLotserial(PXAdapter adapter)
        {
            if (AvailToPick.Count == 0)
            {
                foreach (INItemLotSerial pick in AvailSerialList.Select(this))
                {
                    AvailToPick.Add(pick);
                }
            }
            if (SerialFilter.AskExt() == WebDialogResult.OK)
            {
                GenerateSoShipmentSplitLine();
                DeleteAllTempRecords();
            }
            DeleteAllTempRecords();
            SerialList.Cache.Clear();
            SerialList.Cache.ClearQueryCache();
            return adapter.Get();
        }
```

However when I hit this event, the count shows zero.

```
 protected void InfoLotSerialFilter_LotSerialNbr_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e, PXFieldUpdated InvokeBaseHandler)
        {
            if (InvokeBaseHandler != null)
                InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
            var row = (InfoLotSerialFilter)e.Row;
            if (row.LotSerialNbr != null)
            {
                if (AvailToPick.Count > 0)
                {
```

Any insight as to why the list contents are cleared would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Every callback recreates the graph. Most likely your FieldUpdated event is happening in separate callback which is the reason why list getting cleared.  Also noticed in your action delegate, you are passing "this" to AvailSerialList.Select(this) which should be "Base" instead?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that instead of the list you create a simple View for INItemLotSerial that will create a cache when the page is run.  You can Insert records into the cache during your action and then push them into a List<> and count them during your event.

Comment: Thank you Patrick, I'll try this approach.